# How to select the first available option in <datalist>?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm working with  element and want it to select the first matching element automatically.

My idea was to create a custom KeyboardEvent when  is clicked, then dispatch it when the user is typing something (at first just on click), so with every keypress 'arrow down' will be triggered programmatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <input list="country" id="list">
        <datalist id="country">
            <option value="Armenia">
            <option value="Argentina">
        </datalist>
    </form>
    <script>
list.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let key = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {code: "ArrowDown", keyCode: 40})
    list.dispatchEvent(key)
})
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the actual action to be executed that will be identical to pressing the 'arrow down' key, but this 'parody' event doesn't do anything. If add `addEventListener` to listen for `keydown` event, it never gets triggered.

Comment: Not that this is likely to solve your problem, but I wanted to mention that this `{code: "ArrowDown", keyCode: 40}` should be `{key: "ArrowDown", keyCode: 40}`.

Comment: Actually both `code` and `key` attributes have the same value when I try to print to the console a random keypress. But this just mimics the actual event with pressing keys with these values.

Comment: You're not selecting the element properly. You can't just say 'list'. `document.getElementById("list");`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: But it works fine even in the strict mode. This is not the reason my code doesn't work the way I want it to.